# Need help with creating a texture baked UV image map NOT using nodes on Blender ver 2.79b

Tags: texturing, uv

I need help with creating a baked textured UV map image to wrap a mesh in an inworld game.

I am using Blender 2,79b 2018-03-22 version on a macbook air.

I am NOT using nodes/cycles so I need help with the old school way to texture bake UV image maps.

I do not want to generate a UV map that has to be textured in photoshop. Blender should be able to generate a fully textured UV image map.

I have read & watched so many tutorials and I cannot reproduce the results that they achieve despite following the steps. It always borks at the bake stage.

Essentially how do I create a baked UV image map that I can save and upload into a game to wrap the mesh model.

I have a mesh that has modifiers. And I have a seamless texture.

Initially, I have two material faces as noted by the colors. I will change this to a single white material for now and later can tackle step by step for faces.

Process steps:

I created a cube.

In edit mode, I applied two materials - one to the cube then a second to the top only.

Edited cube to angle sides, removed bottom face, subdivided top face.

Then used an array modifier to make the grid of cubes.

Then went back into edit to rough it up a bit with the sculpt tool.

Then, to lower poly count, used the decimate modifier.

Then used smart UV unwrap.

The texture I have is a seamless rock texture.

This is where I am stuck.

To make it easier, before I unwrapped the mesh, I set the mesh to only one material.

In the texture tab I added the texture.

In UV window, I tried to upload texture then another time uploaded a blank texture per another tutorial…

Ackk… It doesn’t work so starting where I have set the entire mesh to one material then unwrapped the mesh, what do I do next?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hello anbd welcome. Step by step tutorials are off topic here, please narrow down your question to the single issue you are facing that can be answered in a single focused post

Comment: I don't know what the single issue is because I am not sure which step I may be doing that is incorrect.  I listed my process.  Is there a step by step forum that would be more appropriate?

Comment: You can try https://blenderartists.org

Comment: I have.  Had no replies to specifically address this.

Comment: Maybe retitle your question to focus more on your specific issue

Comment: Ok.  Did that. TY.

Comment: I suppose it'll be quite complex to find help on 2.7x versions now, especially for baking in Blender Internal, it'd be simpler for baking in Cycles. The concept in Internal is to select all faces on UV map and then open image to bake to in the UV editor. Internal render doesn't need material to bake to, so your material will be used as source